# Celsius symbol in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, windows, .net-2.0, richtextbox

I write windows application using C# and .NET2.0.
In RichTextBox I would like to show Celsius symbol.
How to do it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you mean Celsius symbol as in `37°C`? If so you can simply put that character where it should be, I guess:

```
 richTextBox.Text = string.Format("{0}°C", degrees);
```

If you are looking for character codes (or just want to find character to copy/paste them), you can use the Character Map application in Windows (in Start -> Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools).

Comment: Yes - I mean degree symbol. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Do you mean °C? You get ° from the keyboard as ALT + 0176 on the numeric keypad.

Comment: Yes, I mean degree symbol. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you are wary of embedding a non-ASCII character in your source code, you could use the following instead:

```
richTextBox.Text = string.Format("{0}\u00B0C", degrees);
```

(`B0` is the hexadecimal for `176`.)

Answer (score 1):

`richTextBox1.Text = "°"` will display a degree symbol in a rich textbox but I'm pretty sure you want something else. Please rephrase your question if that's the case.

Comment: Celsius symbol - I mean degree symbol ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
&deg; //html entity.
```